# How to implement hardware that remembers previous value in digital logic design?

Tags: digital-logic, flip-flop

I am trying to design the following:

- The datapath of an octal calculator which has a 24-bit input register in
  reg and a 24-bit accumulator acc.
- The contents
  of both registers are displayed as eight octal (radix-8) digits.  Both are cleared on reset.
- The calculator has
  buttons for C (clear), the numbers 0-7, and the functions +, -, and x. Pressing C once clears in
  reg.
- Pressing C a
  second time with no other intervening keys clears acc. Pressing a number shifts in
  reg to the left three bits and
  puts the number pressed into the low three bits.
- Pressing a function performs that function on the two registers
  and puts the result in acc. Draw a block diagram from the datapath of this calculator

What I have so far is:

- reg_in and acc flip flops, with the same clock and reset
- an ALU(performing function operations) taking in input from in_reg and acc and outputting back into in_reg, driven by an ALUselect signal
- a shift register to shift the input bits by 3 and put them back into the reg_in

However, the part that I am stuck on is how to implement the "pressing C" part. What design choice can I make which will allow me to clear reg_in if C is pressed once and clear acc if C is pressed again? I want to a find a simpler method than using a counter.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Additional one-bit register should solve the problem. Let's call it `last_button`.

- Set `last_button` to `1` if C is pressed and `last_button` is previously `0`.
- Set `last_button` to `0` if another button is pressed.
- If `last_button` is `0` when C is pressed, clear `reg_in`.
- If `last_button` is `1` when C is pressed, clear `acc`.
- In case `acc` is cleared, clear `last_button` to `0` as well.

You can assume this logic is a Mealy machine with 2 states, then `last_button` is the state signal. C button always toggles the state, other buttons set the state to zero. The outputs (clear `reg_in`/`acc`) of the machine depend on both the inputs (buttons) and the current state.